# Why are the creatures (passive and hostile) all invincible?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

For some reason when I was playing Ark Survival Evolved, when I got hungry, I went to attack a dodo and it was invincible. It didn't even try to run away like normal. So I though okay, little glitch, so I went to another dodo and it was invincible as well. I went to fish, invincible, Pachys, invincible, freaking brontos, invincible. If anyone knows the cause of this, could you please tell me what it is and how to fix it? And I play on PS4 if that helps.

Comment: If the environment doesn't react at all, i.e. creatures don't take damage and don't flee or attack you, it can mean that you lost the connection to the server or the connection is bad (lag).

Comment: Makes sense, but I don't play Online. Although at that time it was lagging a lot less. Does that mean that the game was just screwing up?